# What's the difference bettween Fielddata enabled vs eager global ordinals for optimising initial search query latency in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch (7.10) cluster running that is primarily meant for powering search on text documents. The index that I'm working with does not need to be updated often, and there is no great necessity for speed during index time. Performance in this system is really needed for search time. The number of documents will likely always be in the range of 50-70 million and the store size is ~300GB once it's all built.

The mapping for the index and field I'm concerned with looks something like this:

```json
"mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "document_text": {
                "type": "text"
            }
      }
}
```

The `document_text` is a string of text anywhere in the region of 50-500 words. The typical queries being sent to this index are `match` queries chained together inside a `boolean should` query. Usually, the number of clauses are in the range of 5-15.

The issue I've been running into is that the initial latency for search queries to the index is very high usually in the range of 4-6s but after the first search the document is cached so the latency becomes much lower <1s. The cluster has 3 data nodes, 3 master nodes and 2 ingest/client nodes and is backed by fast SSD. I noticed that the heap on the data nodes is never really under too much pressure nor is the RAM this led me to realize that the documents weren't cached in advance the way I wanted them to be. From what I've researched I've landed on either enabling `fielddata=true` to get the field data object in memory at index time rather than constructing that at search time. I understand this will increase pressure on the JVM heap so I may do some frequency filtering to only place certain documents in memory. The other option I've come across is setting `eager_global_ordinals=true` which in some ways seems similar to enabling `fielddata` as it builds the mappings in-memory at index time also. I'm a bit new with ES and the terminology between the two is somewhat confusing to me. What I'd love to know is what is the difference between the two and does enable one or both of them to seem reasonable to solve the latency issues I'm having or I have completely misunderstood the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling `eager_global_ordinals` won't do any kind of effect on your queries. Enabling global ordinals would only help for aggregations, `doc values` would be loaded at index refresh time instead of loading them at query time.

Enabling `fielddata` would also not do any real effect on your queries. Its primary purpose is sorting and aggregation, which you don't really want to do on a `text` field.

There's probably not much you can do with first ES queries being slower. Better focus on optimal index mappings, settings, shards, and document sizes.